# Linq extension method to query a table

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I have a table which is looks like below (its an audit table and contains data from different tables) with some other column:
I am trying to get all value from the audit table where table name column contains table which has top and EntiryId is 1007 and the notification column

```
Table Name      EntityId
    AllTOP      1007
ProductTOP      1007
ProductTOP      1008
ProductTOP      1007
UserRoleTOP     1007
UserRoleTOP     1008
UserRoleTOP     1007
RequestTypeTOP  1007
Notifications   1014
Notifications   1015
Notifications   1016
```

I have tried below:

```
var logList = _dbcontext.Audits.Where(e => e.TableName.Contains("TOP") && e.EntityId == 1007.ToString()).ToList()
```

this query gives me the result with value which contains top but when I am trying to add another condition to get all value from Notification I am getting "Enumeration returns no result". Here is my try

```
var logList = _dbcontext.Audits.Where(e => e.TableName.Contains("TOP") && e.EntityId == 1007.ToString() && e.TableName.Contains("Notifications")).ToList()
```

what is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for this:

```
var logList = _dbcontext.Audits
  .Where(e => (e.TableName.Contains("TOP") || e.TableName.Contains("Notifications")) 
  && e.EntityId == 1007.ToString()).ToList()
```

Column names should be connected with logical OR (||) not AND (&&). This is assuming that the `EnitityId` condition should be there regardless it is `Top` or `Notifications`.

Answer (score 0):

AND operand && acts in this way that all of conditions must be true for a row to select that row. With the data that you provided you need this query :

```
var logList = _dbcontext.Audits.Where(e => (e.TableName.Contains("TOP") || e.TableName.Contains("Notifications"))
&& e.EntityId == "1007" ).ToList()
```